# Row by row calculation over several files c++

Tags: c++, modeling

I have 4 text files with the same number of rows and columns. I am modeling a set of time-dependent variables using a 5th order RK scheme, each line of input on these files represents some parameters from a unique dataset. These parameters are needed to solve the equations in my model. I want to loop through each line of input from the four input files, get the values of these parameters, do the RK method, and store the dependent-variable values in time as a single line of output in an output file.

for a single file i have used:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <valarray>
#include <vector>
#include<string>
#include<sstream>

using namespace std;

typedef valarray<double> val;



//void read_X(ifstream &infile, val(&x)); void read_I(val(&I));

struct Inf {

int i, j;

double Iij;

double ton, toff; };

istream& operator >> (istream &is, Inf &s) {

string line;

getline(is, line);

istringstream ss(line);

ss >> s.i >> s.j >> s.Iij >> s.ton >> s.toff ;

return is; 
}

vector<Inf> Xdata;

val Iij(20);


int main() { 

Iij = 0;


ifstream infile("Data.txt");


Inf I;

if(infile.is_open()){
while (infile >> I) Xdata.push_back(I);
} 

else cerr << "The file cannot be opened" << endl;


for(Inf s : Xdata) cout << s.ton << " " << s.Iij << endl;


infile.close();

return 0; 
}
```

My data.txt file has contained something like;

> 1   1  0.1204 0.0  1.170
>
> 1   2  0.142  1.0  1.170
>
> 1   3  0.523  5.0  5.170
>
> 1   4  0.200  2.0  4.170
>
> 2   1  0.400  3.0  4.170
>
> 2   2  0.120  0.0  1.170
>
> 2   3  0.120  0.0  1.170

Is there a way I can do this for multiple files? I have thought of a vector of structs, but I am not sure how practical it will be. I will appreciate all the help I can get.

PS: I have a working code for the RK method already for a single case, I just need to loop over several data sets.

Thank you!

Comment: I have tried using a vector of structs, but I could only populate it for one of the files and not all.

Comment: Please edit your post with [mcve].

Comment: Just add another loop that iterates over the filenames, before the line with `ifstream infile("Data.txt");`.

Comment: How do you mean?